# How to blend an image with a solid colour in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to blend an image with a solid colour using CSS. How can this be done?

This is what I've got so far:

```
header {
  width: 900px;
  height: 60px; 
  background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
  background-color: rgba(51,102,153,0.5);
}
```

It's not working though!

I just can't get my head around this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why don't you use a (semi)transparent image - e.g. `png`?

Comment: because I am using that image in another place as well and I don't want two files

Comment: Does the image have a transparent background?

Comment: Then convert it to a .png with a transparent background, and use it as an `<img>` tag with the bg color set on the parent.

Comment: OK, that would be an option but not working in this case because the image is too complex to be formatted as a PNG. But thanks!

Comment: Ohh, I misunderstood what you mean, based on the solution. That is a relatively easy thing to do :)

Comment: Just set an opacity on the img.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two divs, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqmb5/1/):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
    background: url("http://sp9.fotolog.com/photo/41/8/54/butterlyinthebox/1243705008574_f.jpg") no-repeat;
}

#content
{
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 477px;
    height: 318px;
}
```

Comment: I would advice against publishing a content image as a background image.

Answer (score 6):

The currently accepted answer and it's alternative indeed work. But both use background-image's for actual content. This method uses an img tag.

HTML

```
<div class="blend">
<img src="http://sp9.fotolog.com/photo/41/8/54/butterlyinthebox/1243705008574_f.jpg" alt=" " />
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.blend {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.blend img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

​See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzexG/).

Comment: Looking at it now... this might be more semantic with an <figure> tag.

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer works, but it's semantically incorrect and would benefit from some optimisations.

You can use the pseudo after element for this, so you don't need to introduce additional markup for this. So the markup remains this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

The CSS is verbose, but more expressive. I don't like that the "wrapper" contains the actual content (image), while the "content" is just a simple color. Also there is no need to fade the whole div, but you can use the alpha channel for the color.

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    background: url("http://sp9.fotolog.com/photo/41/8/54/butterlyinthebox/1243705008574_f.jpg") no-repeat;
    width: 477px;
    height: 318px;
}
#content:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[​jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzexG/)

Comment: Thanks! This one is quite elegant indeed.